# Unable to complete Thieves Guild quests/achievement when selling the armor given to you?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Basically the same question as this:
[Where can I get Thieves' Guild armour?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/36687/where-can-i-get-thieves-guild-armour)

However, I know damn well where I sold my armor - the fence that now wants it!  I can't get it back, help!

I've tried:

- Pickpocketing her (she doesn't have it)
- Adding via console.  I got the item id's here:
  http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Armor

I get 'Item X Added', yet it doesn't actually show up in my inventory.  I'm running:

```
player.additem 00036584 1
```

I also found this:
http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Thieves_Guild_(faction)#Fences

Notes:

> (IMPORTANT!) When you obtain the Thieves Guild Armor DO NOT SELL IT!
>   Otherwise Tonilia will not be able to upgrade it.
>   She will continuely ask to upgrade it and no other dialogue options will be available.
>   Not only will you lose her as a fence, but you will not receive the Achievement/Trophy (One with the Shadows) of Restoring the Thieves Guild. This is because Tonilia is the last objective.

Anyone know why I can't add this item via console?

Comment: Ha ha ha ha ha ha ha ha. I think I may have done the same thing!

Comment: Dammit - I sold mine too....didn't realize it'd be such a huge problem later on. :/

Comment: Sometimes thieves run around in Rifton, maybe you could kill one of them and get it back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go into console by pressing <kbd>~</kbd> (the button under ESC on the far left), type:

```
coc qasmoke
```

Once in there go to the "All Standard Armour" chest. Find the Armour here eg. Thieve guild armour capacity 20 and loot it. Once looted, type:

```
coc whiterun
```

and fast travel to the thieves guild and hand in. Hope this helps.

Comment: You my friend are my hero.

Comment: You're most welcome :)

Comment: Did this disable achievements?

Comment: This doesn't disable achievements.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37996/9382):

```
player.additem 000d3ac2 1
player.additem 000d3ac3 1
player.additem 000d3ac4 1
player.additem 000d3ac5 1
```